# 80386 Microprocessor Segmentation Unit Size

Tags: memory, memory-management, architecture, microprocessors, memory-segmentation

I'm learning 80386DX microprocessor with 32 bit data bus & 32 bit address bus. 80386 can have max 4GB physical memory & can have 16384 segments of 64KB each. But most of the online & book resources say that any single segment can have any varying size ranging from 1Byte all the way to 4GB max.

So how is it possible that 80386DX can have max 16384 segments in physical memory ?

If I keep 1GB as my segment size I'd have 4 segments in total, so if I keep my segments size 16KB, I should be able to have more than 16384 segments ?

Answer (score 0):

What you refer is the Memory Management Unit which has two sub components which is Segmentation unit and Paging unit. If you refer to segmentation, you can get variable length segments of 64 Kbytes in size of each. Else you can refer to paging as size of 4GB units. Anyways task on 80386 can have a maximum of 16,381 segments of up to 4GB each,
thus providing 64 TB of virtual memory to each task